# How to read AVRO files captured by Azure Event Hubs from Synapse SQL Serverless

Tags: avro, azure-synapse, azure-data-lake-gen2, azure-eventhub

I receive realtime data through an Azure Event Hubs, which captures and stores directly to an Azure Storage Account. I'd prefer a parquet format, however it is not possible because only DataLake V1 is supported for parquet files, and it is not avilable in my Azure region.
Now that I have such AVRO files, I'd like to read them from Synapse without moving them, as Synapse SQL Serverless can do very well for CSV, Json and Parquet files. In fact my idea was to create some CET tables which are just wrapper around data stored in the storage account.

But the problem is that it seems that Synapse cannot read this AVRO format, so I'm stuck. Any help, really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you adjust the Event Hubs Capture to [write to Parquet files](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/messaging-on-azure-blog/azure-event-hubs-capture-event-streams-in-parquet-format-to-data/ba-p/3418086#:%7E:text=Capture%20streaming%20data%20in%20Parquet%20format%20using%20Event,job%20without%20writing%20a%20single%20line%20of%20code.) in ADLS Gen2. Then you can query it in Synapse Serverless SQL easily.